# Formally conjuguate to its linear model

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I'm doing this problem in Complex Analysis :

Let $\lambda \in \mathbb C^*$ not be a root of $1$. Consider $F(z) = \lambda z + \sum_{n=2}^\infty a_nz^n$. Show there exists a power series $g(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_nz^n$ such that $b_1 \not =  0$ and $F(g(z))=g(\lambda z)$. We say that $F$ is formally conjuguate to its linear model $z \mapsto \lambda z$.

I don't really know what to do, I think we have to define explicitly $g$, maybe with $b_n$ having  $1-\lambda^n$ in the denominator, since $\lambda^n \not=1$.

Comment: Is this from a book, by the way? If it is, could you please post the book title? I think I might be interested.

Comment: Maybe, I found it here https://www.math.ens.psl.eu/~odegaay/TDanalysecomplexe2022.pdf  It's exercise 1.10.

Comment: Here's one incentive to learn French :-) Thanks!

Comment: These are exercices from a Complex Analysis course from ENS Paris. Good luck !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$F(g(z)) = \lambda g(z) + a_2 g(z)^2 + a_3 g(z)^3 + \ldots\qquad (1),$$

$$g(\lambda z) = b_1 \lambda z + b_2 \lambda^2 z^2 + b_3 \lambda^3 z^3 + \ldots \qquad (2).$$

If you expand $(1)$ as power series and equate the coefficients before $z^n$ with $(2)$, you get an infinite system of algebraic equations on $b_i$'s. The coefficient $b_1$ can be set almost freely (I would just use $1$, however there might be other choices with deeper reasons); then $b_n$ is determined using $a_i$'s and $b_j$'s ($j < n$).
I think the key point here is that the equations I mention have form $p_n(b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_{n-1}, a_1, \ldots, a_n) = (\lambda - \lambda^n) b_n$, the first power coming from the first term of $(1)$, and the $n$-th, from the $n$-th term of (2). If $\lambda$ is not a root of unity, you will be able to carry out the step-by-step solving indefinitely, since $p_n$ are all polynomials.